# What current evidence supports the use of hydroxycloroquine used as a prophylactic for (corona)-viral infections?

Tags: virology, coronavirus

I've also read comments from doctors suggesting that hydroxychloroquine has been studied in the past as a potential prophylactic for viral infections.  A search through US clinical trials yields many results which mention this drug in connection to lupus, arthritis, and cancer.  But I have yet to find completed clinical trials which revolve around viral infections - does this exist somewhere or has this never been studied?

Comment: What has your research shown?

Comment: SE Biology is a question and answer site concerned with the mechanisms of biological processes, as you will see if you finish reading the Tour. Your question is about the results of clinical trials, which do not come into this category. There are ample reputable sources that provide expert and up-to-date information about efforts to combat the coronavirus, [some of which are listed on our meta site](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/information-about-coronaviruses/4036#4036). Please consult that.

Answer (score 2):

The only double blind randomised clinical trial I am aware of is [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8565026) one, examining the use of hydroxychloroquine for the treatment of HIV-1-infected patients.  It finds significant reductions in viral load, but not improvement of CD4+ counts.  How much change could be expected in 8 weeks I do not know.  There are in vitro studies, such as [this one](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4350140/) looking at dengue virus.

In combination with azithromycin it has been examined for the use in [COVID-19 (pre-print, not peer reviewed)](https://www.mediterranee-infection.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/COVID-IHU-2-1.pdf), but without a control group I find it hard to call it a clinical trial, and there are [other criticisms](https://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/archives/2020/03/29/more-on-cloroquine-azithromycin-and-on-dr-raoult) of the work.